# Degrees of Polynomials that Converge Uniformly to a Non-Polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, polynomials

I'm reading Neal Carothers' *Real Analysis* and there's a problem I'm stuck on: Let $p_n$ be a real-valued polynomial of degree $m_n$, and suppose that $(p_n)$ converges uniformly to a real-valued, continuous function $f$ on $[a,b]$, where $f$ is *not* a polynomial. Show that $(m_n)\to \infty$. Here's what I've done so far:

Let $S_D$ be the set of all polynomials over $[a,b]$ with degrees between $0$ and $D$ inclusive. If I can show that this set is closed with respect to $C[a,b]$ (the set of all real-valued, continuous functions over $[a,b]$) under the supnorm metric, I will have shown that no sequence from $S_D$ converges uniformly to $f$, since $f$ is not an element of $S_D$.

However, I haven't had any luck doing so; I've also tried showing that the complement of $S_D$ is open, but to no avail. I also thought about doing an induction argument on $D$. Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $S_D$ is a finite-dimensional normed space.

Comment: Just as a follow up question: Since your hint implies that $S_{D}$ is complete: does that mean since $(p_{n})$ uniformly converges to $f$, $m_{n} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ since $f$ is not a polynomial?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Essentially, yes.